# Do USB D-/D+ lines for PIC18 require EMI (RC) filtering?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I recently ran into an issue with USB cable lengths and an FT230XS where I didn't include the 47R and 27pF on the data lines. I'm working on a project now where I use CDC for communication so I have the D+/D- lines going directly to a PIC18F2550. Do I need to include any RC for this situation? I've had some trouble locating answers for this specific situation.

edit: also, for whatever reason, would the 5 pin header for programmer jtag need filtering as well? I haven't used any RC on the programmer jtag before, but if it's the "correct" way to do it I'd like to.

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'd suggest moving this to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Although it is always recommended to include pull-up resistors for USB lines, the PIC18F2550 already has internal resistors that can be used for this. Please check pages 163 to 167 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632c.pdf).

As for the capacitors, I don't find them always necessary, but it doesn't hurt to leave the space for them in case you need them further ahead.

Never seen resistors or capacitors for the JTAG header.